# Need single spaced table notes with double spaced entire document

Tags: threeparttable, tablenotes, threeparttablex

I am using a class file specified by my university which sets the line spacing for the whole document to double. However, I want the notes underneath my tables to be single-spaced which are currently double-spaced due to the class file's setting. Here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass[oneside,final, letterpaper]{ucr}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable} %Package required to write notes under the table.
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs,caption}
\newcommand{\al}{\addlinespace}

\begin{document}


\begin{table}
 \centering
    \caption{Regressions Using Cross-sectional Data}
        \label{tab:cross-section}   
    \begin{threeparttable}  
        \begin{tabular}{lcc} \toprule
                     & (1) & (2) \\
            VARIABLES & Real GDP pc & Real GDP pc \\ 
                      & Growth (1970-1990) & Growth (1970-1999) \\ 
                      \midrule
                    &  &  \\
            SXP & -0.0431* & -0.0375* \\
             & (0.0181) & (0.0159) \\
                \addlinespace
            Initial Log Real GDP pc & 0.000809 & 0.00152 \\
                                             & (0.00177) & (0.00155) \\
                \addlinespace
            Open & 0.000147* & 0.000155*  \\
             & (5.80e-05) & (4.85e-05)  \\
                \addlinespace
            Log Investment pc (1970-1990) & 0.0101* & 0.00826*  \\
             & (0.00356) & (0.00312) \\
            \addlinespace
            Constant & -0.0226 & -0.0255* \\
             & (0.0139) & (0.0121) \\
             &  &  \\
            Observations & 104 & 104 \\
             R-squared & 0.189 & 0.228 \\ \hline
        \end{tabular}
        \vspace{1em}
        \begin{tablenotes}
          \small          
          \item Note: All the variables except Initial Log Real GDP pc in column 1 are averaged over the period 1970-1990, and in column 2 are averaged over the period 1970-1995. Standard errors in parentheses. * p$<$0.05. 
        \end{tablenotes}  
        \end{threeparttable} 
            \end{table}

\begin{table}
\renewcommand\thetable{2.1}
\caption{Calibrated parameter values (continued)}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{c c c} \toprule
Parameter & Parameter definition & Calibrated value \\ \midrule \midrule \al
$\gamma_\pi$ & Sensitivity of interest to inflation & 2.43 \\ \al
$\phi_{TR_{ss}}$ & Government Transfer to GDP ratio & 0.01 \\ \al
$\phi_{B_{ss}}$ & Public debt to GDP ratio & 1 \\ \al
$\phi_{I_{ss}}^G$ & Public investment to GDP ratio & 0.02 \\ \al
$\gamma_G$ & Government consumption persistence & 0 \\ \al
$\gamma_{I}^G$ & Persistence of public investment & 0.1 \\ \al
$\gamma_{TR}$ & Persistence of income transfer & 0.1 \\ \al
$\gamma_{\tau^c}$ & Persistence of consumption tax & 0 \\ \al
$\gamma_{\tau^l}$ & Persistence of labor income tax & 0 \\ \al
$\gamma_{\tau^k}$ & Persistence of capital income tax & 0 \\ \al
$\phi_G$ & Government consumption to debt ratio & 0 \\ \al
$\phi_{I}^G$ & Public investment to debt ratio & -0.1 \\ \al
$\phi_TR$ & Government transfer to debt ratio & -0.1 \\ \al
$\phi_{\tau^c}$ & Consumption tax to debt ratio & 0 \\ \al
$\phi_{\tau^l}$ & Labor income tax to debt ratio & 0 \\ \al
$\phi_{\tau^k}$ & Capital income tax to debt ratio & 0 \\ \al
$\eta$ & Labor tax schedule level & 0.7 \\ \al 
$\phi_n$ & Labor tax schedule slope & 0.3 \\ \al
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

I looked at previous posts where `setspace` package has been used and `\singlespacing` has been added right after `\begin{threeparttable}`. But merely writing `\usepackage{setspace}` seems to conflict with the caption of my second table, and produces the following error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\setstretch ...ef \baselinestretch {#1}\@currsize
l.15 ...on{Regressions Using Cross-sectional Data}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed.
```

I will appreciate if anyone could help me out here.

P.S. The LaTex templace suggested by my university could be downloaded from here: http://graduate.ucr.edu/filingresources.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class *doesn't* use `setspace`.

Solution: use `\linespread{1}` before `\small`. Without `\small` it should be `\linespread{1}\selectfont`.

```
\documentclass[oneside,final, letterpaper]{ucr}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs,caption}
\newcommand{\al}{\addlinespace}

\begin{document}


\begin{table}
 \centering
    \caption{Regressions Using Cross-sectional Data}
        \label{tab:cross-section}   
    \begin{threeparttable}  
        \begin{tabular}{lcc} \toprule
                     & (1) & (2) \\
            VARIABLES & Real GDP pc & Real GDP pc \\ 
                      & Growth (1970-1990) & Growth (1970-1999) \\ 
                      \midrule
                    &  &  \\
            SXP & $-$0.0431* & $-$0.0375* \\
             & (0.0181) & (0.0159) \\
                \addlinespace
            Initial Log Real GDP pc & 0.000809 & 0.00152 \\
                                             & (0.00177) & (0.00155) \\
                \addlinespace
            Open & 0.000147* & 0.000155*  \\
             & (5.80e$-$05) & (4.85e$-$05)  \\
                \addlinespace
            Log Investment pc (1970-1990) & 0.0101* & 0.00826*  \\
             & (0.00356) & (0.00312) \\
            \addlinespace
            Constant & $-$0.0226 & $-$0.0255* \\
             & (0.0139) & (0.0121) \\
             &  &  \\
            Observations & 104 & 104 \\
             R-squared & 0.189 & 0.228 \\ \hline
        \end{tabular}
        \vspace{1em}
        \begin{tablenotes}
          \linespread{1}\small
          \item\hspace*{-\fontdimen2\font}Note: All the variables except
            Initial Log Real GDP pc in column 1 are averaged over the period
            1970-1990, and in column 2 are averaged over the period 1970-1995.
            Standard errors in parentheses. *~$p<0.05$. 
        \end{tablenotes}  
        \end{threeparttable} 
            \end{table}

\end{document}
```

I've made some other changes, notably `-` into `$-$` for minus signs and `*~$p<0.05$` for an italic “p” and no line break between the asterisk and the formula.

I also added a trick for removing the unwanted space before “Note”.

[image]

Comment: awesome! Thank you. I didn't know that "Without \small it should be \linespread{1}\selectfont". That's why my linespread command was not working.

Comment: @TRa Yes, in order to have effect `\linespread{x}` should be followed by `\selectfont` (which is included in `\small`). The effect is local, so it will vanish after `\end{tablenotes}`.

Answer (score 1):

The class defines the `\ssp` command. Use it at the beginning of the `tablenotes`:

```
    \begin{tablenotes}
      \small\ssp
      \item Note: All the variables except Initial Log Real GDP pc in column 1 are averaged over the period 1970-1990, and in column 2 are averaged over the period 1970-1995. Standard errors in parentheses. * p$<$0.05.
    \end{tablenotes}
```

[image]